# Database access through VB

Tags: vb.net

I am accessing a database through vb adodb connection.
I have added

```
Module Module1
    Public con As New ADODB.Connection
    Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Public Sub connection()
        con = New ADODB.Connection
        con.Open("Database1.mdb")
    End Sub
    Public Sub opentable(ByRef str As String)
        rs = con.Execute(str)
    End Sub
End Module
```

and

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim first As String
    Dim second As String
    Dim str As String
    
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connection()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        opentable("INSERT INTO [User] (FirstName , SurName) VALUES('" & first & "','" & second & "')")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Problem is that when ever I am accessing I am getting the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using VB 6 or COM in VB.Net,

change your connection string to something like this

```
con.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=fullpath\Database1.mdb;")
```

Comment: @user3302024 why don't you accept this as the answer?